# How to return to parent process after child process exit in gdb

Tags: gdb

I want to debug a cgi (fork-exec)

```c
  pid = fork();
  if ( pid >= 0 )
  {
    if ( !pid )
    {
      cgi(fd, url, a3, data, count);  <<- debug into internal
      exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid, stat_loc, 0);
    ++count;
  }
  else
  {
    sub_1C45((unsigned int)fd);
  }
```

but I can only break point at cgi internal once because cgi will exit and my gdb will terminate. But parent process is alive.
So, Have some ways to let gdb return parent process after child process exit?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read about [multiple inferior debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html), [non-stop mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html) and `set detach-on-fork off` ([documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks)).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void cgi() { sleep(1); }

int main()
{
  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    printf("child: %d\n", getpid());
    cgi();
  } else {
    printf("parent: waiting for: %d\n", pid);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("parent: %d exited\n", pid);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Suppose I want to stop on the `cgi()` routine in the child and also after `waitpid()` in the parent. Here is a transcript:

```
gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from a.out...

(gdb) set non-stop on
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off

(gdb) b cgi
Breakpoint 1 at 0x117d: file t.c, line 5.

(gdb) b 16
Breakpoint 2 at 0x11f4: file t.c, line 16.

Starting program: /tmp/a.out
[New inferior 2 (process 2766133)]
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/7b/9682d06533ba6fb9a8099004cbc6b17c1433f4.debug...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/3a/5d7d8c50feeea2504b130bc627fef68364d927.debug...
parent: waiting for: 2766133
child: 2766133

Thread 2.1 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 1, cgi () at t.c:5
5       void cgi() { sleep(1); }
```

At this point, the child (inferior 2, thread 1) is stopped on the breakpoint. But that is not our current inferior, so we must switch to it:

```
(gdb) info inferiors
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable
* 1    process 2766129   1 (native)           /tmp/a.out
  2    process 2766133   1 (native)           /tmp/a.out
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [process 2766133] (/tmp/a.out)]
[Switching to thread 2.1 (process 2766133)]
#0  cgi () at t.c:5
5       void cgi() { sleep(1); }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 2 (process 2766133) exited normally]
(gdb)
Thread 1.1 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 2, main () at t.c:16
16          printf("parent: %d exited\n", pid);
```

Now we've hit the breakpoint in the parent process. But the parent process is (no longer) the current inferior, we must switch back to it:

```
info inferiors
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable
  1    process 2766129   1 (native)           /tmp/a.out
* 2    <null>                                 /tmp/a.out
(gdb) inferior 1
[Switching to inferior 1 [process 2766129] (/tmp/a.out)]
[Switching to thread 1.1 (process 2766129)]
#0  main () at t.c:16
16          printf("parent: %d exited\n", pid);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
parent: 2766133 exited
[Inferior 1 (process 2766129) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```